# Question about topological hourglass

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X:=[-1,1]\times \mathbb{S}^1$, where each space is taken with the usual euclidean topology.
Let $S:=\{0\}\times \mathbb{S}^1 \subseteq X$ and call $H:=X/S$.

> Is $H$ normal?

My only idea is the following, but I'm stuck on it, plus I would like a more 'direct' approach.

Calling $C:=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2=z^2, z \in [0,1]\}$ and $f: X \rightarrow C$, $f(x,y,z)=(x|z|,y|z|,z)$, we have that $f$ is continuous and surjective and it makes the same identifications as the projection from $X$ to $X/S=H$, so If I knew it is an identification I would get that $C$ and $H$ are homeomorphic.

Since $C$ is a subspace of a $T4$ and $T1$ space it is itself $T4$ and $T1$ $\implies $ normal, and $H$ would be itself normal.

My questions are: how can I show that $f$ is an identification? Is there a more direct approach, that requires no homeomorphisms? (I'm not allowed to use the fact that closed identifications normal spaces map into normal spaces)

---

$H$ is a normal space if it is $T1$ and $T4$ (where $T4$:= closed disjoint non empty sets can be separated by disjoint open sets)

Comment: Do you know what the quotient looks like geometrically?

Comment: @G.Chiusole To me it looks like $C$, two closed cones with the same vertex

Comment: $X$ is normal and the quotient map is closed so...

Comment: @Matematleta I asked not to use this result in the question, is there a way around this?

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your post fully. What type of proof are you looking for?

Comment: @Matematleta Apart from not using that fact I'd like to see a different approach from mine, which I'm not sure is the one intended in the exercise from which my question arises (i.e. showing if $Y$ is Hausdorff, normal or metrizable , questions that become easy if I show the homeomorphism)

Comment: From scratch I guess it's enough to show that if  $A$ is a subset of $H$ and $N$ is an open in  $X$ containing  $p^{-1}(A)$, then there is an open $U$ in  $H$ containing $A$ such that $p^{-1} (U)$ is contained in $N$. Then, take two disjoint closed sets in $H$, pull back to $X$ then use normality of $X$ plus what we have just shown, to conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is compact and $C$ is Hausdorff, thus $f$ is a closed map. Closed surjective maps are identifications.